# Length contraction and Spacetime diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

[image]

I don't understand why $x_c=l/\sqrt{1-v^2}$

if interval between A and C is equal, then:

$$ l^2=-t^2+(x_c)^2$$

thus :

$$ x_c=\sqrt{l^2-t^2} $$

why is:

$$ x_c=\frac{l}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} $$

Please show me detail calculation

Comment: That looks familar. Is it from Bernard Schutz's book?

Comment: Check out wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction#Derivation

Comment: Please don't cut and paste stuff on the internet without attribution. It's rude. I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use that tag on this type of problem. Please don't paste bitmapped images of material as a question. That makes search engines not able to search the site, and makes the site inaccessible to blind people.

Answer (score 4):

First, your notation for the time coordinate of an event is ambiguous.  Second, you have a sign error in your calculation

In the primed coordinate system, the event $\mathcal{A}$ has coordinates $(0,0)$ and the event $\mathcal{C}$ has coordinates $(0,l)$.  The interval in the primed coordinates is then

$$\Delta s^2_{\mathcal{AC}} = l^2 $$

In the unprimed coordinate system, $\mathcal{A}$ has coordinates $(0,0)$ and $\mathcal{C}$ has coordinates $(t_\mathcal{C},x_\mathcal{C})$.  The interval in the unprimed coordinates is then

$$\Delta s^2_{\mathcal{AC}} = -t^2_\mathcal{C} + x^2_\mathcal{C}=$$

thus

$$x^2_\mathcal{C} - t^2_\mathcal{C} = l^2  \rightarrow x_\mathcal{C} = \sqrt{t^2_\mathcal{C} + l^2}$$

*This* is just invariance of the interval.

But we also know that $\mathcal{C}$ is on the $x'$ axis and (see the preceding pages in your textbook) the $x'$ axis in the unprimed coordinate system is the line $t = vx$ and so

$$x^2_\mathcal{C} - t^2_\mathcal{C} = x^2_\mathcal{C} - v^2x^2_\mathcal{C} = x^2_\mathcal{C}\left(1 - v^2\right) \rightarrow x_\mathcal{C} = \frac{l}{\sqrt{1 - v^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\def\bK{\bar K} \def\bt{\bar t}  \def\bx{\bar x} \let\D=\Delta \let\g=\gamma$
You could think that everything has been said and another answer is useless. But there is something I always find missing when length contraction is discussed. To explain my point I want to begin with time dilation.

What is this issue about? We have two *events*, $E_1$ and $E_2$. We also have two frames $K$ and $\bK$, the latter moving wrt $K$ with velocity $v$ in positive direction. We know that events $E_1$ and $E_2$ happen in the same position of $\bK$, their time separation being $\D\bt$. We are asked to compute time separation in $K$.

*Solution*. Let's name $\D t$ the requested time separation in $K$. In this time lapse frame $\bK$ has moved a space $\D x=v\,\D t$. By invariance of interval we have 
$$c^2 \D t^2 - \D x^2 = c^2 \D\bt^2$$
$$c^2 \D t^2 - v^2 \D t^2 = c^2 \D\bt^2$$
$$\D t^2 = {c^2 \D\bt^2 \over c^2 - v^2}$$
$$\D t = {c\,\D\bt \over \sqrt{c^2 - v^2}} = 
  {\D\bt \over \sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}}.$$

---

One would be tempted to apply an analogous reasoning for Lorentz contraction. The argument could run as follows. Let's name $A$, $C$ (like in your figure) two events, simultaneous in $\bK$, happening at the ends of the rod, at a distance $l_0=\D\bx$. Then the coordinates of $A$, $C$ in $\bK$ are
$$(\bx_A, \bt_A) = (0,0) \qquad (\bx_C,\bt_C) = (\D\bx,0).$$

Using Lorentz transformations we find
$$(\bx_A, \bt_A) = (0,0)$$ 
$$\bx_C = \g\,\D\bx$$
$$l = \bx_C - \bx_A = \g\,\D\bx = \g\,l_0$$
which is not what we expected and is exactly what you did.

Maybe my detailed explanation will have shown where the catch is: time
dilation and length contraction *are not analogous or symmetrical* to
each other. My point is that I have never seen this explicitly said.
In Lorentz contraction we are not interested in what happens to two
assigned *events* seen from two different frames. We are interested in
two *objects* (this is the word I like to use, to distinguish from
events), in our case the rod's ends.

An object is not a point in spacetime, it is a *worldline*. In our simple case, a straight line. We wish to compute the distance between left end's worldline and right end's one in frame $K$, given that in frame $\bK$.
Distance is meant *at a given time of that frame*.

The right way to do it (shortcuts apart) is to determine the
worldlines' equations. In frame $\bK$ this is trivial:

left: $\bx_L = 0$

right: $\bx_R = l_0$.

As to frame $K$, use Lorentz transformation in the reverse:
$$\bx = \g\,(x - v\,t)$$
Choosing $t=0$ as the time to compute distance:
$$x_L = \bx_L/\g$$
$$x_R = \bx_R/\g$$
$$l = x_R - x_L = (\bx_R - \bx_L)/\g = l_0/\g.$$